# UPS on SharePoint 2013 - Single - Dev Server

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, ups, forefront

I was unable to start the "User Profile Synchronization Service". Then I tried to start the "Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service" from the services and both attempts failed. Then I wanted to check weather miiclient.exe exists or not. I don't see even the folder "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers".

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: I see it's possible to have UPA in single dev server. Is there a reason for SP not to install this piece. Or do I need to do something so miiclient.exe forefront is installed or created?

Comment: I found it. It was in the D: drive where sharepoint was installed. Now I need to figure out why it doesn't want to start. D:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell

Comment: Follow the step by step in this article without skipping ANY steps and you should be good: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx This article works EVERY time. It says 2010 but it applies to 2013 as well. Never attempt to start FIM manually, you should only let SharePoint handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed all the genius links and nothing helped. so I finally applied December 2016 CU (kb3128005) then psconfig. The server had to restarted afterwards. The UPA sync was not starting so I did following and ran the autofixer. Now it's all up.

```
# STOP THE UPA SYNC THAT'S HANGING
$TypeName = "User Profile Synchronization Service"
$ServerName = "USHUBSPS13DEV01"
$Serviceinstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | where-object {$_.TypeName -eq $TypeName -and $_.Server.Address -eq $ServerName}
$Serviceinstance.Unprovision()
```

https://sharepointbjorn.com/2014/06/25/user-profile-synchronization-autofixer/